# helm-find-file (and other things) appearing in my main split

Tags: helm, window, window-splitting

I currently have `helm` installed.

Sometimes when I have my window split vertically, when I run `helm-find-files`, it appears in one of the already open windows, rather than creating a new horizontal window at the bottom. Is there a way of ensuring that it always creates a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the following:

> (setq helm-split-window-in-side-p t)

appears to resolve your issue.